# How to retrieve Oracle server collation in order to set up linked server

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2000, collation

After searching here and on the web, I finally decided to post the question. I am running an SQL 2000 server, and linked an Oracle 9i server. Everything works fine when I run queries, and even updates and inserts from and to the Oracle Linked server (using both Microsoft OLE DB driver and Oracle OLE DB driver) using the OPENQUERY approach.
The problem is that, in order to clean code a bit, I want to use four part names in my queries. I am doing this also when querying other SQL linked servers.

But when I run the queries against Oracle using four part names I get this error: ( I am translating the error message from spanish. Probably the original message in english id different)

ERROR: OLE DB 'MSDAORA' returned an invalid column definition.
Error Code: 7318

Digging a bit, I learned that this is probably related to nos having the right collation name set in the linked server properties.

Now... I am not an Oracle expert, so I need to find out what collation is the schema I connect to using in Oracle (apps... yes, I know, I know... )

So, the plain question is... How do I find out what collation Oracle is using? I have access to the Oracle server via Toad... is there any query I can run in order to find this out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the NLS settings, which you can find from these views:

- V$NLS_PARAMETERS — "Current values"
- NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS — What the database was created with.
- NLS_INSTANCE_PARAMETERS — From changes by ALTER SYSTEM
- NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS — Combined, plus ALTER SESSION
- V$PARAMETER — System parameters, where a lot of this is changed (contains all kinds of stuff)

The documentation is rather lacking here (or, quite likely, I couldn't find the right document), but this should get you what you want.

You will probably have to log in as SYSDBA to read some of these views.

Comment: Hi... thanks for your reply.
I already tried this, but accessing those parameters through Toad... unfortunately I can't find here what I'm looking for...
This is a [screenshot](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5654637/imagenes/NLS.png) of the parameters I get.

As you can see, the only two parameters that could possibly be related to my collating issue are **NLS_CHARACTERSET: WE8ISO8859P1** and **NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET: AL16UTF16**

Comment: If any of these are, I guess I need to find an equivalent to the collate names I see in the [selection list](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5654637/imagenes/collate.png) when I set up the linked server in SQL

Maybe I'm missing something... any other hint?

Thanks

Comment: @jprealini: Well, it appears you're using Latin1 (ISO 8859-1) and your collation ([NLS_SORT, NLS_COMP](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch3globenv.htm#sthref362)) is binary. Not sure how that maps into SQL Server.

Comment: @jprealini: Doing some Googling, it appears you want one ending with _BIN. Maybe Latin1_General_BIN. Got that from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188046.aspx